# Html Tags In salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using below code but i am facing an issue like.
System.PageReference has no member named getparameters at line 6 column 19

Visualforce:

```
   <apex:page controller="Html">
    <apex:form >
   Name :<input type="text" name="txt1"/> <br/>
   <apex:commandButton value="SAVE" action="{!save}"/>
  </apex:form>
   </apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```
 public class Html {
 public void save() {
 Account acc = new Account();
   **acc.Name = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('txt1');**
     //      error line        
   insert acc;
 }}
```

Comment: I tried running the code and I didn't get an error..

Comment: @martin but for me it showing an error,Martin i am using correct code..?

Comment: In your class, I see no getter for your variable `txt1`, nor a declaration for it either.

Comment: You might want to try using the apex:param tag in a command link. I've found that to be a pretty reliable way of passing a value from a visualforce page back to a controller.

Comment: why not use `apex:inputText value="{!txt1}` and bind that to `public String txt1 {get; set;}` instead of the `<input ...>` ?  This would be standard VF practice